# Apache Zeppelin gives error when using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, apache-zeppelin

The following piece of code works fine when I run the script in pycharm

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

c1 = mpatches.Patch(color="green",label="No Traffic")

c2 = mpatches.Patch(color="red",label="Traffic")

df = predict_df.limit(100).toPandas()

colors = {0:"red",1:"green"}


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.scatter(df["avgSpeed"],df["vehicleCount"],df["avgMeasuredTime"],c=df["prediction"].apply(lambda x: colors[x]),s=100,marker="o")

ax.set_xlabel('avgMeasuredTime')

ax.set_ylabel('avgSpeed')

ax.set_zlabel('vehicleCount')


plt.title("BiKmeans Traffic Data")


plt.legend(handles=[c1,c2])
plt.show()
```

I have installed matplotlib using pip, also based on some similar questions tried to install as sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
but I get the same error in Zepplin,

```
 File "/home/benjamin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 280, in <lambda>
    key=lambda col: col.do_3d_projection(renderer), AttributeError: 'PathCollection' object has no attribute 'do_3d_projection'
```

The version of matplotlib is 2.2.0